# How can I solve $y=a^x+x$ for x?

Tags: exponential-function

I am looking for how to isolate x, or basically find the inverse function of $f(x)=a^x+x$. I don't have much experience with these types of equations, nor with non-elementary functions which may be necessary for this. I tried moving x over to the other side and taking a log, but that doesn't seem to bring me any closer to a solution.

Comment: You have $1$ equation with $2$ unknowns, what kind of solution are you hoping for? Or have you missed out some information?

Comment: I think that, we have to find $x$ in terms of $y$.

Comment: OR , he accidentally wrote $f(x)$ as $y$ and he was supposed to find solutions of $f(x)=2^x+x$ i.e. standard roots?

Comment: Rather, find  $f^{-1}(y)$. @TheDeadLegend

Comment: I changed the question slightly to make it more clear and general

Comment: volcanrb  "Feel free to use" the question field, into which you can edit your question to make more clear, as well as to include your own efforts.

Comment: And volcanrb, please "demonstrate step-by-step" what **you** yourself attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=a^x+x$$

Assuming $a>0$:

$$-x+y=e^{x \ln a}$$

Let $u=-x+y$ so that $x=-u+y$ and we get,

$$u=e^{(y-u) \ln a}=\frac{a^y}{e^{ u\ln a}}$$

So we have,

$$ue^{u \ln a}=a^y$$

$$u \ln a e^{u \ln a}= a^y\ln a$$

Now we utilize the lambert $W$ function which is defined by $W(x)e^{W(x)}=x$.

$$u \ln a=W(a^y \ln a)$$

$$u=\frac{W(a^y \ln a)}{\ln a}$$

$$x=y-\frac{W(a^y \ln a)}{\ln a}$$

Comment: I would provide the definition for Lambert's W-function in this answer out of personal preference, $x=W(x)e^{W(x)}$ and mention that $W(x)$ is Lambert's W-function.

Answer (score 1):

Given $y$ you want $$(y-x)a^{y-x}=a^y$$

Letting $u=(y-x)\log a$ you get:

$$ue^u=a^y\log a$$

So $u=W(a^y\log a)$ and $$y-x=\frac{W(a^y\log a)}{\log a}$$

Or $$x=y-\frac{W(a^y\log a)}{\log a}$$

Here, $W$ is [Lambert's W-function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: I would provide the definition for Lambert's W-function in this answer out of personal preference, $x=W(x)e^{W(x)}$.